# c# convert YUV 4:2:2 to RGB?

Tags: c#, rgb

I have a screen grabber which gives me a image in YUV 4:2:2 format.

I need to convert my byte[]'s to RGB format?

Please help,
Jason

Comment: Have you read this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Conversion_to.2Ffrom_RGB :)

Comment: This one should also be useful: [Converting Between YUV and RGB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms893078.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/colorspace1.aspx) to convert from RGB, YUV, HSB, HSL and many other color formats, example using the static method at RGB class to convert from YUV, just call

```
RGB rgb = RBB.YUVtoRBG(y, u, v);
```

And the underlying implementation of it:

```
public static RGB YUVtoRGB(double y, double u, double v)
{
    RGB rgb = new RGB();

    rgb.Red = Convert.ToInt32((y + 1.139837398373983740*v)*255);
    rgb.Green = Convert.ToInt32((
        y - 0.3946517043589703515*u - 0.5805986066674976801*v)*255);
    rgb.Blue = Convert.ToInt32((y + 2.032110091743119266*u)*255);

    return rgb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using integer only calculations (i.e. should be quicker than float/double calculations) is:

```
    static byte asByte(int value)
    {
        //return (byte)value;
        if (value > 255)
            return 255;
        else if (value < 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return (byte)value;
    }

    static unsafe void PixelYUV2RGB(byte * rgb, byte y, byte u, byte v)
    {
        int C = y - 16;
        int D = u - 128;
        int E = v - 128;

        rgb[2] = asByte((298 * C + 409 * E + 128) >> 8);
        rgb[1] = asByte((298 * C - 100 * D - 208 * E + 128) >> 8);
        rgb[0] = asByte((298 * C + 516 * D + 128) >> 8);
    }
```

here you use the PixelYUV2RGB function to fill values in a byte array for rgb.

This is much quicker than the above, but is still sub-par in terms of performance for a full HD image in c#.

Note that this is just for YUV to RGB. YUV 422 is stored with 2 Y (lightness) values for every pair of UV (colour) values. So you will call the function with the same u, v values for each pair. The source for this is mentioned in comments below.

Comment: -1 A) site your [sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917087.aspx); B) this converts from YUV 4:4:4, not 4:2:2

Answer (score 0):

There is code [here](http://pastebin.com/MFsDnUCq) to do exactly what you want, but the byte order for the RGB bitmap is inverted (exchange the reds and blues).